# i want to display the picture in one page by js,but onclick does not work

Tags: javascript, html

This is the page to show picture, replace placehold with different source by js.
I don't want it to go to another page when I click the `<a>` link, so I'm using using `onclick="return false"`. But it doesn't work. I can't find the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>my first gallery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/showPic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Snapshot</h1>
    <a href="images/6.jpg" onclick="return false; ">Click me</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="images/1.jpg" onclick="showPic(this);
            return false;" title="first picture" >my favorite </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        **<a href="images/2.jpg" onclick="showPic(this); return false;" title="second picture">second my favorite</a>**
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ol>
        <li>
        <a href="images/3.jpg" onclick="showPic(this); return false;" title="third picture" >third my favorite </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="images/4.jpg" onclick="showPic(this); return false;" title="forth picture" >forth my favorite </a>
        </li>
    </ol>
<!--this the place to show pictures-->
    <img id="placeholder" src="images/5.jpg" alt="place holder imga" />

</body>
</html>




JS:
function showPic(whichPic){
    var source = whichPic.getAttribute("href");
    var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");
    placeHolder.setAttribute("scr", source);

}
```

Comment: Would you please post your JavaScript code? That would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which bit doesn't work? First thing I noticed is that you have a spelling mistake when setting the placeholder's attribute. you have scr when it should be src

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your JavaScript replaces the placeholder with an image using `href` as the source. Instead, I would reccomend that you do this:

```
<span onclick="showPic('images/4.jpg');" title="fourth picture" >fourth my favorite</span>
```

You will need to edit the JavaScript accordingly. I can show you how if you post the script code.